# How do you solve this problem from Kangaroo Math Competition 2016 Junior?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Dates can be written in the form DD.MM.YY. For example, today's date is 17.03.2016. A date is called "surprising" if all 8 digits in its written form are different. In what month will the next surprising date occur?

From what I understand, I think we need to make sure that the year does not have a 1 digit, a 0-digit, or a 2-digit, in order for us to be able to maximize the probability that the month is a number underneath 10. However, I do not know where to go from there. Any help? The answer is June, but I do not know why.

Answer (score 4):

The day starts with 0,1,2 or 3, and the month starts with 0 or 1. So the year can contain at most two of the digits 0 to 3.

Using this fact, I'll try to find the first year that could have a surprising date.

> If the year contains 2 and 0 then 1 and 3 must be used in the day and month. So 3 is used to start the day number and 1 starts the month. A day starting with 3 must end with 0 or 1, which will be a repeat. So the year cannot contain both 2 and 0.
>
>  The same argument works if the year contains 2 and 1.
>
>  Therefore the year cannot start 20 or 21, but maybe could start with 23, as long as it does not contain 0 or 1. The first year this happens is 2345.

Now I'll try to find the first month in that year that could have a surprising date:

> The day and month must use 0 and 1. The first month that uses exactly one of 0,1 and not any digits of the year is 06. The first day that works is then 17. The first surprising date is therefore 17-06-2345.

So the answer is June.

Answer (score 0):

*Ab ovo*, for a given month, choose the smallest day that minimizes the year.

Month 01, Day 27, Year 3456

Month 02, Day 17, Year 3456

Month 03, Day 17, Year 2456

Month 04, Day 17, Year 2356

Month 05, Day 17, Year 2346

**Month 06, Day 17, Year 2345**

Month 07, Day 16, Year 2345

Month 08, Day 16, Year 2345

Month 09, Day 16, Year 2345

Month 10, Day 27, Year 3456

Month 11, Day 30, Year 2456

Month 12, Day 17, Year 3456

Answer (score -1):

I assumed that the year of the nearest surprising date is $2XXX$. Then the month must be $0X$. The day must be $1X$ since $31$ forces the year to be $24XX$. Hence the year is $2345$ and the month of the nearest surpring date is $06.$ It is june.